# how to remove an element forcefully using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I'm using a plugin and I don't know from where the same div is repeated. So I'm trying to remove the repeated div

Suppose I have the following markup.....

```
<div id="main">
<div>
    <div>
<div>
    <p class="test">hi this is test</p>
</div>
<div>
    <p class="test">hi this is test</p>
</div>
    </div>
</div>
    </div>
```

jquery

```
/*how can I forcefully remove this so that later on this div cannot be cloned*/
$('.test').closest('div').next().remove();
/* suppose this is in plugin */
$('.test').clone().appendTo('#main');
```

[updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5xyR9/3/)

Comment: So what the Problem is ??, its working you just have not included the jquery

Comment: jquery is not included in the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/HeHks/1/

Comment: did you add the code in dom ready handler

Comment: please check the updated demo...\

Comment: @ArunPJohny yes! it's inside dom ready

Comment: Remove it forcefully? You need the _.terminateWithPrejudice()_ plugin.

Comment: actually the proper way is to understand why your code is producing an unrequired element, did u try using `:not(:first)`

Comment: @mikakun yes tried that but no success...

Comment: working perfectly well you end up with 2 test, if it was not working you'd get 4... see edit in answer

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#main .test:not(:first)').parent().remove();
```

guessing  the plugin is adding the clone upon instantiating which you don't want, it seems (shall be cloned on some plugin event triggering only i presume?) so do it after instantiating your plugin that add the clone you don't want

```
$('#main .test:not(:first)').parent().remove();
/* suppose this is in plugin */
$('.test').clone().appendTo('#main');
$('#main .test:not(:first)').parent().remove();
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using the parent selector instead.

```
$('.test').parent('div').remove();
$('.test').clone().appendTo('#main');
```

The `closest` method traverses up the ancestor tree as far as it needs to go to find a selector match. It will return either `0` or `1` element(s).

The `parent` method only looks at the direct parent. It will return `0` or `more` elements

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vpE49/)

Comment: Going to need more information then, the answer to your initial problem was because you were using the wrong selector the was only returning the first element it found. What plugin are you working with?

Comment: [imgscroller for joomla 2.5](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/photos-a-images/rotators/images-rotators/8742)

Comment: Both _.closest()_ and _.parent()_ will return  one element at most _if called on a jQuery object that only contains one element._ Both methods can return many elements if called on a jQuery object that contains many elements.

Comment: NavinRauniyar your fiddle has the `.next()` selector, remove it. Take a look at the fiddle I posted in my original answer.